# Using namespaces with JAXB and JSON under Jersey 2.2 JAX-RS

Tags: json, namespaces, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I am using xjc to compile an XML schema with namespaces and ANY elements.  I will be including elements from external namespaces as needed and need to handle the situation where a new version of an element definition is included, or perhaps a element from another namespace with the same name.  Obviously, the XML version of this is working perfectly and I get the correct QNAME for all elements on the client side, however, for the JSON I get an unqualified QNAME with only the element name present. This means I cannot distinguish between and element called "bob" from one namespace, versus a different element called "bob" from a second namespace.

I have read all the material I can find, and believe this is what I need to do on the server side, however, i do not know what I need on the client side:

```
@Provider
final static class JsonMoxyConfigurationContextResolver implements ContextResolver<MoxyJsonConfig> {

    @Override
    public MoxyJsonConfig getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        final MoxyJsonConfig configuration = new MoxyJsonConfig();

        Map<String, String> namespacePrefixMapper = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
        namespacePrefixMapper.put("http://schema.jaxbmoxy.examples.jersey.glassfish.org/2013/08/customer", "c");
        namespacePrefixMapper.put("http://schema.jaxbmoxy.examples.jersey.glassfish.org/2013/08/other", "o");

        configuration.setNamespacePrefixMapper(namespacePrefixMapper);
        configuration.setNamespaceSeparator('.');

        return configuration;
    }
}
```

The "c" schema is the base schema I have defined, and the "o" schema holds the element definitions I will incorporate through the ANY.  For the example below I am importing o.stats and o.email from the external namespace.  Below is the JSON being generated on the server side:

```
{"c.customer": [
    {
        "id": "3",
        "personal-info": {
            "name": "Bobby Boogie",
            "o.stats": [{
                "age": "45",
                "height": "160 cm",
                "weight": "70 kg"
            }]
        },
        "contact-info": {
            "address": {
                "city": "My Town",
                "street": "123 Any Street",
                "country": "CA"
            },
            "phone-number": [
                {
                    "type": "work",
                    "value": "613-555-1111"
                },
                {
                    "type": "cell",
                    "value": "613-555-2222"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "personal-info": {
            "name": "Fred Finkleman",
            "o.stats": [{
                "age": "55",
                "height": "182 cm",
                "weight": "86 kg"
            }]
        },
        "contact-info": {
            "address": {
                "city": "Fredsville",
                "street": "1 Happy Street",
                "country": "US"
            },
            "phone-number": [
                {
                    "type": "work",
                    "value": "613-555-1111"
                },
                {
                    "type": "cell",
                    "value": "613-555-2222"
                }
            ],
            "o.email": ["fred@email.com"]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "personal-info": {
            "name": "Tom Dooley",
            "o.stats": [{
                "age": "45",
                "height": "160 cm",
                "weight": "70 kg"
            }]
        },
        "contact-info": {
            "address": {
                "city": "My Town",
                "street": "123 Any Street",
                "country": "CA"
            },
            "phone-number": [
                {
                    "type": "work",
                    "value": "613-555-1111"
                },
                {
                    "type": "cell",
                    "value": "613-555-2222"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]}
```

What configuration code do I need on the client side so i can get this to function correctly?  At the moment I have the following:

```
@Override
protected void configureClient(ClientConfig clientConfig) {
    clientConfig.register(new MoxyXmlFeature());
    new ResourceConfig().property(MarshallerProperties.JSON_NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR, ".");
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to set the `MarshallerProperties.NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER` property to match the one you have set on the server side.

Edit: I have a feeling Blaise's answer provided above is correct, however, it introduces a different issue that I can only assume is a bug under Jersey 2.2.  Here is the client code segment I created based on Blaise's answer:

```
@Override
protected void configureClient(ClientConfig clientConfig) {
    Map<String, String> namespacePrefixMapper = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
    namespacePrefixMapper.put("http://schema.jaxbmoxy.examples.jersey.glassfish.org/2013/08/customer", "c");
    namespacePrefixMapper.put("http://schema.jaxbmoxy.examples.jersey.glassfish.org/2013/08/other", "o");

    clientConfig.register(new MoxyXmlFeature());
    clientConfig.register(new MoxyJsonFeature());
    clientConfig.property(MarshallerProperties.NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER, namespacePrefixMapper);
    clientConfig.property(MarshallerProperties.JSON_NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR, '.');
}
```

On the client side I am now getting a NPE during processing of the incoming JSON:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unexpected error during response processing.
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:767)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:90)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:671)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:422)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:396)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:296)
at org.glassfish.jersey.examples.jaxbmoxy.MoxyAppTest.testJsonCustomer(MoxyAppTest.java:172)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONReader.parse(JSONReader.java:264)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONReader.parse(JSONReader.java:443)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONReader.parse(JSONReader.java:424)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONReader.parse(JSONReader.java:241)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONReader.parse(JSONReader.java:443)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONReader.parse(JSONReader.java:296)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONReader.parse(JSONReader.java:443)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONReader.parse(JSONReader.java:424)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONReader.parse(JSONReader.java:241)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONReader.parseRoot(JSONReader.java:174)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JSONReader.parse(JSONReader.java:125)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:972)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:425)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:375)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:705)
at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:655)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:301)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:580)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:188)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:134)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:988)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:833)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:768)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:96)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:761)
... 41 more
```

Now all is not lost.  I was able to fix the issue by adding attribute prefix processing.  On the server side I added to *JsonMoxyConfigurationContextResolver.getContext()*:

```
configuration.setAttributePrefix("@");
```

And on the client side I added the following to *configureClient()*:

```
clientConfig.property(MarshallerProperties.JSON_ATTRIBUTE_PREFIX, "@");
```

I am now getting the correct processing of the incoming JSON and the namespace has been added to the QNAME of the included JAXB elements.

Thank you for the help!!